# Azure DevOps Pipeline CMake with MSVC and NMake

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to set up an Azure DevOps pipeline on Windows, compiling my code with cmake and generating nmake files, then calling nmake. However, after setting up the path to `cl.exe` through the cmake, it fails at testing the compilers while calling `nmake`. I've tried adding to path within `CMakeFiles.txt`, adding a command line before the CMake which adds the `nmake` to `PATH` (which I've verified exists and contains `nmake`), and finally calling `cmake` in the same command line as adding to `PATH`, except none of these options worked. When I add to `nmake` to `PATH` using a separate command line before, it mysteriously disappears by the next instruction.
How would I set up my build to compile with `cmake` then `nmake`?

edit: this is my current generated yaml, calling everything within the same command line. The "View YAML" button on the pipeline doesn't do anything, so this is just for the command block

```
steps:
- script: |
   set PATH="%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\hostx86\x86\"
   dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\hostx86\x86\"
   echo %PATH%
   "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -G "NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_SH="CMAKE_SH-NOTFOUND" $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)
   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\hostx86\x86\nmake.exe" $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)\build
   displayName: 'compile with cmake'
```

Comment: Can you post your yaml?

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to do this recently and wanted to post something so others won't have to go through the educational effort that I did.

The VS version is controlled by the image you choose in Azure
You do not need to worry about it

```
Windows-latest == VS 2022 (Currently)
Windows-2019   == VS 2019 (Version 16)
Windows-2017   == VS 2017 (Version 15)
```

NOTE: It is expected that you have already built this locally and have working CMakeLists.txt files in place for CMake to process

============= Basic pipeline using VS 2019 and CMake

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'Windows-2019'

- task: CMake@1
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: Debug
    cmakeArgs: -S $(BUILD.SOURCESDIRECTORY)\TopDirectory -B $(BUILD.SOURCESDIRECTORY)\TopDirectory\Debug -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A Win32
```